# Passing a route path as a method parameter without evaluating it first

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, parameter-passing

I have a Organization model with a simple `validates :name, presence: true` validation.

To DRY up some code I have a "helper" method in my `ApplicationController` as follows:

```
def handle_errors(object, message, origin, target)
  if object.invalid?
    yield if block_given?
    render(origin)
  else
    redirect_to(target, flash: { notice: message })
  end
end
```

This works very well on the `update` action:

```
@organization = Organization.find(params[:id])
@organization.update(organization_params)
handle_errors @organization, "Updated organization", 'edit', organization_path(@organization)
```

However, in the `create` action

```
@organization = Organization.new(organization_params)
@organization.save
handle_errors @organization, "Updated organization", 'new', organization_path(@organization)
```

it breaks when you fail the validation (i.e., enter a blank name-field) with the error

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"organizations", :id=>nil} missing required keys: [:id]
```

The id-key is missing because `@organization` is unsaved and `@organization.id = nil`. Since the route path method is evaluated before it's passed to the `handle_errors` method it generates an error.

What I would like to do is to "evaluate the route path" later (only in the `else`-case of the `handle_errors` method). One way to do this would be to wrap the route path in a lambda block and call the method as follows:

```
handle_errors @organization, "Updated organization", 'new', lambda {organization_path(@organization)}
```

Yet another way to solve the problem would be to instead of passing the route path to the `handle_errors` method is to just pass the object (or an array for nested resources and custom actions-name)

```
handle_errors @organization, "Updated organization", 'new', [@organization]
```

But is there any other way to do this in an even more ruby/rails oriented way?

Comment: Try `@oragnization` instead of `organization_path(@organization)`

Comment: @BroiSatse I mentioned that in my last example, although enclosed in an array.